# Combine string recursive-python

Tags: python

I have two string list:
A = ['YELLOW']
B = ['BA']

I want to combine these two string using a recursive function to get 
['YBAEBALBALBAOBAWBA']

HERE IS my function :

```
def Combine(A, B):

    if len(A) > 0:
        return str(A[0]) + str(B) + Combine(A[:0], B)
```

--
I have no idea how recursive works?
Could someone please help me!

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close!

```
def Combine(A, B):
    if len(A) > 0:
        return str(A[0]) + str(B) + Combine(A[1:], B) # <-- fix 1
    else:
        return '' # <-- fix 2
```

1. in order to call recursively with the rest of `A` you should call `A[1:]`
2. you took care of the case that `len(A) > 0` but forgot to take care of the case that `A` ran out of characters (the `else`)

**Running**

```
A = 'YELLOW'
B = 'BA'

print(Combine(A, B))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
YBAEBALBALBAOBAWBA
```